# Could a user space process start a root sub-process?

Tags: linux, process, file-permissions, root, viber

I am using Ubuntu Linux and I have Viber proprietary software running on it. Today I saved a file using Viber and I realized that it has been stored in file system with *root* user as its owner. I dug more and I realized there are two process running, one under my user name another under root. Could somebody explain me if it is possible for a process in user space to start another subprocess as a root?

Here is permissions of the file stored with Viber:

```
mehdix@spielplatz:~/New Folder2$ ls -l
total 240
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 245455 Okt  9 09:50 saved_with_viber
```

and here is the ’ps’ command result:

```
mehdix@spielplatz:~$ ps axuf | grep Viber
mehdix   23857  0.0  0.0   4444   644 ?        S    Okt08   0:00          \_ /bin/sh /usr/share/viber/Viber.sh
root     23864  0.0  1.8 2794592 146604 ?      Sl   Okt08   0:17          |   \_ /usr/share/viber/Viber
mehdix   26484  0.0  0.0  17432   964 pts/5    S+   09:43   0:00                  \_ grep --color=auto Viber
mehdix@spielplatz:~$
```

Here is output of ’ls -l /usr/share/viber/Viber’:

```
mehdix@spielplatz:~$ ls -l /usr/share/viber/Viber
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 1733113 Okt 31  2013 /usr/share/viber/Viber
```

and here is contents of ’/usr/share/viber/Viber.sh’:

```
mehdix@spielplatz:~$ cat /usr/share/viber/Viber.sh
#!/bin/sh
appname=`basename $0 | sed s,\.sh$,,`

dirname=`dirname $0`
tmp="${dirname#?}"

if [ "${dirname%$tmp}" != "/" ]; then
  dirname=$PWD/$dirname
fi

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$dirname
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Sure. Look up SUID.

Comment: @Bob I don't understand the situation. I'm pretty sure that a user-space program should never be able to run anything as root, then how it can start a root sub-process and mark file permissions as root? Or am I wrong entirely?

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -l /usr/share/viber/Viber` and post `/usr/share/viber/Viber.sh` somewhere ? That might tell us what's going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. A file with the [SUID permission bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) set will run under the file owner rather than the user who launched it. An SUID file owned by root will run under root.

`sudo` is an example of such a program. You can launch it from any user, but it will run under root and can launch further processes with root privs.

As you can see in your `ls -l` output, this is the method being used here: the file is owned by `root` and the SUID bit is set (as indicated by the `s` instead of `x` for user execute permissions). In fact, it looks like the SGID bit is also set.

Comment: When I run ’sudo’ I must provide root password but when I launch Viber I don't provide any password. Does it matter?

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi The password is requested and managed by the `sudo` binary and has **nothing** to do with SUID - it occurs *after* the binary has been executed under the `root` user. The SUID and other permissions functionality is managed by the kernel (`exec`).